# Creating an Adjacency Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, network-analysis

I have read a lot about creating an adjacency matrix in R. But I have a slightly odd requirement, I cannot crack the data structure for.

I have a data set that looks like this.

| Case | Person | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC01 | 99999 | Plaintiff |
| ABC01 | 11111 | Defendant |
| ABC02 | 22222 | Plaintiff |
| ABC02 | 99999 | Defendant |
| ABC03 | 33333 | Plaintiff |
| ABC03 | 44444 | Defendant |
| ABC04 | 55555 | Plaintiff |
| ABC04 | 66666 | Defendant |
| ABC05 | 99999 | Plaintiff |
| ABC05 | 88888 | Defendant |
| ABC06 | 77777 | Plaintiff |
| ABC06 | 22222 | Defendant |
| ABC07 | 11111 | Plaintiff |
| ABC07 | 44444 | Defendant |
| ABC08 | 44444 | Plaintiff |
| ABC08 | 99999 | Defendant |

Hopefully the columns are self-evident. The output of the adjacency matrix should look something like this where for each case (dropped from the final table) a unique count of each parties involvement in each role should be output. this would allow for a network analysis of plaintiffs and defendants.

| Plaintiff | Defendant | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99999 | 11111 | 1 |
| 22222 | 99999 | 1 |
| 33333 | 44444 | 1 |
| 55555 | 66666 | 1 |
| 99999 | 88888 | 1 |
| 77777 | 22222 | 1 |
| 11111 | 44444 | 1 |

Note that as the plaintiff and defendant switch roles their index is repeated. But if there are multiple lawsuits between the same to parties in the same positions than this should be reflected in the count of incidents.

This is the current solution

```
df %>% 
group_by(Case,Person) %>% 
mutate(count = n()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(row=row_number())%>%
spread(Status,count)
```

The issue with is solution is that rows are offset.

| Crime Reference Number | Person Record URN (ACN) | row | Plantiff | Defendant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACB01 | 8645499 | 1610 | 1 | NA |
| ACB02 | 8620113 | 1456 | NA | 1 |
| ACB02 | 8708027 | 1457 | 1 | NA |
| ACB03 | 8667531 | 1455 | 1 | NA |
| ACB04 | 8650244 | 1458 | 1 | NA |
| ACB05 | 8613947 | 1214 | 1 | NA |
| ACB06 | 9074764 | 1022 | 1 | NA |
| ACB07 | 8949458 | 1459 | 1 | NA |

And help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign an id column for `Case` and get the data in wide format. Then use `count` to count how many times the combination of `Plaintiff` and `Defendant` occur.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Case = dense_rank(Case)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from = Person) %>%
  count(Plaintiff, Defendant)

#  Plaintiff Defendant     n
#      <int>     <int> <int>
#1     11111     44444     1
#2     22222     99999     1
#3     33333     44444     1
#4     44444     99999     1
#5     55555     66666     1
#6     77777     22222     1
#7     99999     11111     1
#8     99999     88888     1
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, as usual I over thought the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), frank(Case, ties.method = 'dense') ~ Status,
     value.var = 'Person')[, .(n = .N), .(Plaintiff, Defendant)]
```

-output

```
  Plaintiff Defendant n
1:     99999     11111 1
2:     22222     99999 1
3:     33333     44444 1
4:     55555     66666 1
5:     99999     88888 1
6:     77777     22222 1
7:     11111     44444 1
8:     44444     99999 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Case = c("ABC01", "ABC01", "ABC02", "ABC02", "ABC03", 
"ABC03", "ABC04", "ABC04", "ABC05", "ABC05", "ABC06", "ABC06", 
"ABC07", "ABC07", "ABC08", "ABC08"), Person = c(99999L, 11111L, 
22222L, 99999L, 33333L, 44444L, 55555L, 66666L, 99999L, 88888L, 
77777L, 22222L, 11111L, 44444L, 44444L, 99999L), Status = c("Plaintiff", 
"Defendant", "Plaintiff", "Defendant", "Plaintiff", "Defendant", 
"Plaintiff", "Defendant", "Plaintiff", "Defendant", "Plaintiff", 
"Defendant", "Plaintiff", "Defendant", "Plaintiff", "Defendant"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```